# Smooth vertices as a group

Tags: modeling, vertices

I have a model made by 2 different people and I am now trying to polish some details myself. I would like to somehow smooth/round all selected vertices as group so that the curve is as nice as the upper one. Is there a way to do it?

[image: editor screenshot]

Comment: Your mesh is unworkable in its current state. The topology is useless for mesh editing. Too many vertices. No surface flow. Your work is going to be made harder that it needs to be because of how it is constructed.  Realize that the more points you have, the harder everything is to control. You should have no more points than is strictly necessary to define changes in curvature. You can always add more geometry later if needed. I recommend box modeling a new version, while using your current one as a visual guide. Keep everything quads, and add a subdivision surface modiifer.

Answer (score 1):

use proportional editting. press 'O' as in Oscar on the keyboard. a little box in the top middle of the screen will highlight. next to that is a dropdown for curve shape or lack there of.

edit: you want to run a remesh modifier. yeah that looks like a nightmare.